# Using the iTunes control keys for VLC

Tags: itunes, vlc, keyboard

VLC responds to the itunes control keys (you know: back, forward, pause/play) on the keyboard.

Yet when I use them, both iTunes AND VLC respond, which is quite stupid. For example: I want to pause a video playing in VLC (iTunes isn't even running) so I press play/pause, VLC pauses yet iTunes launches and starts playing.

How can I temporarily disable the control keys for iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

Running OS X Lion 10.7.2, VLC 1.1.12 -- this desired "proper" functionality suddenly appeared, perhaps as a result of the update from 10.7.1->10.7.2 the other day. Or perhaps as the result of a VLC update.

Control of VLC and iTunes via Apple Keyboard hotkeys is now decoupled. The active player responds to hotkey keypress.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue w/ using the remote on Hulu Desktop and found the following instructions to work perfectly:
http://lifehacker.com/5651055/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-no-manual-hacking-required

Basically, you download a file, double click on it and it frees your media keys from iTunes.  When iTunes is open, they still work with iTunes, so you aren't breaking anything.